# SQL A Union B result different from A+B?

Tags: sql, union

I was using Union to merge two SQL queries, but the results are different from a combination of two different queries.
Below is my SQL code:

```
(SELECT CONCAT(Name, '(', LEFT(Occupation, 1), ')')
FROM OCCUPATIONS
ORDER BY Name ASC)
UNION
(SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ', COUNT(Occupation), ' ', 
LOWER(Occupation), 's.')
FROM OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY Occupation
ORDER BY Occupation ASC)
```

If I only run the first half of the query, I get the following result:

```
Aamina(D) 
Ashley(P) 
Belvet(P) 
Britney(P) 
Christeen(S) 
Eve(A) 
Jane(S) 
Jennifer(A) 
Jenny(S) 
Julia(D) 
Ketty(A)  
Kristeen(S) 
Maria(P) 
Meera(P) 
Naomi(P) 
Priya(D) 
Priyanka(P) 
Samantha(A)
```

If I only run the second half of the query, I get the following result:

```
There are a total of 4 actors. 
There are a total of 3 doctors. 
There are a total of 7 professors. 
There are a total of 4 singers.
```

Both results above are in expected order. However, if I run all the query, I get the following result:

```
Ashley(P) 
Samantha(A) 
Julia(D) 
Britney(P) 
Maria(P) 
Meera(P) 
Priya(D) 
Priyanka(P) 
Jennifer(A) 
Ketty(A) 
Belvet(P) 
Naomi(P) 
Jane(S) 
Jenny(S) 
Kristeen(S) 
Christeen(S) 
Eve(A) 
Aamina(D) 
There are a total of 4 actors. 
There are a total of 3 doctors. 
There are a total of 7 professors. 
There are a total of 4 singers.
```

As you may notice, the order of the first half is screwed. Does anyone know why?
How does Union different from writting two separate SQL query? Thanks!

Comment: Only the last `ORDER BY` in `UNIOIN` is respected.

Comment: `UNION` carries an implicit `DISTINCT` operator.  Try `UNION ALL`.

Comment: @BaconBits I believe there are no results missing, they're only in unexpected order.

Comment: Yes, there are no results missing, only in unexpected order.

Answer (score 2):

The order is not "screwed".  You have no `order by` for the overall query, just for the subqueries.  The ordering is not preserved.  You are using `UNION`, which removes duplicates.

The safe way to execute this query is:

```
select str
from ((select concat(Name, '(', LEFT(Occupation, 1), ')') as str, 1 as which
       from OCCUPATIONS
      ) union all
      (select concat('There are a total of ', COUNT(Occupation), ' ', 
lower(Occupation), 's.') as str, 2 as which
       from OCCUPATIONS
       group by occupation
      )
     ) o
order by which, str
```

Comment: Thanks! Why do you use 'order by which str' in the end?

Comment: @CathyQian Because `which` and `str` are two fields in the subquery that makes up the `from` clause.  `which` has a fixed value of `1` in the first part of the query, and a fixed value of `2` in the second part. This forces the sorting to preserve the order you described.

Comment: BTW, your code works perfect! I just don't understand why the order in subqueries is not preserved when I use UNION? Is there any resources I can look into? Thanks!

Comment: @CathyQian . . . You do not have an `order by` for the overall query.  Hence the results are in an arbitrary order.